# How to create "UINavigationController" with backbutton in Xcode (xib)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

thank you for taking time to answer me !

I'm inexperienced in IOS development, after several searches on google, I turn to you.

My problem is that : I will wish to use UINavigationController, with new main view, to allow me to create a back button.

Here is my AppDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc]init];

//self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

//UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

self.window.rootViewController = mvc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

and my AppDelegate.h :

```
@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

//@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

During development I changed the main view of the application as you can see above the two lines commented out.

I would like to use "UINavigationController" with this new main view, what does it change? and where?

Thank you and sorry if i'm not clear ! (Google Translate)

Comment: Did you try setting MainViewController to inherit from UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `MainViewController *mvc` as the root of your `navController` and make it the root view controller of the window.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: mvc];

self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Comment: It's obvious, now you tell me ! Thank you